# Regular expression for area id in networking

Tags: javascript, regex

Require regular expression for the following format

**Rules:**

1. Allowed values integer `[0-9]`, alphabet `[a-f]` or `[A-F]`
2. Each group can be max of 2 digit and each group should be
   separated by a space
3. There can be max 13 such groups

**Input**

1. 3F 22 11 3F 22 11 3F 22 11 3F 22 11 3F 22 11  (**wrong**)
2. 49 00 01   (**True**)
3. 23    (**True**)
4. 3F 22 11 3F 22 11 3F 22 11 3F 22 11 3F    (**true**)

I tried this but no luck

```
([0-9a-fA-F]{2} (\s){1,13}
```

Comment: Apart from bracket mismatch, missing anchors, `(\s){1,13}`: means, repeat spaces one-to-thirteen times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `([0-9a-fA-F]{2} (\s){1,13}` is that it does not have anchors and the parentheses are not paired. Also, `(\s){1,13}` means *match 1 to 13 whitespaces*. Definitely not what you need.

You can use the following regex:

```
/^[0-9a-f]{2}(?: [0-9a-f]{2}){0,12}$/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zX9aU4/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `[0-9a-f]{2}` - 2 characters from the set - a digit or hex letter
- `(?: [0-9a-f]{2}){0,12}` - 0 to 12 sequences of:

  - - a space (you may use `\s` here to match any whitespace)
  - `[0-9a-f]{2}` - 2 characters from the set - a digit or hex letter
- `$` - end of string.

The `/i` is a case insensitive modifier that lets you use `[a-f]` to match `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` and `F`, too.

Comment: can you please explain this to me and by the way this looks perfect to me as of now

Comment: Could you please let me know what kind of details you need me to dwell on? I included a step by step description, you may also see more "machine"-like explanation at [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/zX9aU4/1).

Comment: oh sorry dont know why is was not showing the pattern details in my browser, now it is coming properly after refresh sorry to bother you thanks